# Why deleting the Anti-forgery cookie manually in the browser and posting gives a 404 (.net core 2.0Razor pages)

Tags: c#, .net-core, http-status-code-404, antiforgerytoken, razor-pages

I am assuming that this is the normal behavior...

When i go to the application tab in chrome developer tools, select and delete the anti-forgery cookie i get a default page not found 404 error.

This is a razor pages web app.

What happens after i perform a post all the way to returning a 404?

Shouldn’t it throw a missing anti forgery exception?

If it is returning a 404, why is it not returning my custom 404 page?

I have tried to create a custom exception middleware and an exception filter but can't catch this exception anywhere.

If instead of deleting the cookie if I manually modify it (chrome's developer tools Application tab) I get a 500 error... Same thing here, can't catch any exception.

Any help is welcome.

[Image of the 404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3ZRC.png)

[Image of 500 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deuKk.png)

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the response is a 404 and not a 400? If request verification fails, the framework should return a 400 Bad Request status code, which would explain why your custom 404 page doesn't work.

Comment: I have updated the question, please look at the images of the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Antiforgery token is required for all POST request made to a razor page. You can disable it globally or for a specific razor page.

For a detailed explanation check the following page:

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/security/request-verification

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I understand that when the Antiforgery feature is enabled it expects the cookie. I am not interested in disabling that feature but in understanding what is the flow of events once I delete that cookie and post.